# javalite could not find or load main class

Tags: java, javalite

After successfully following along the instructions of the javalite example project ([here](https://github.com/javalite/simple-example)), the command line returns:

> Could not find or load main class activejdbc.examples.simple.Main

when trying to execute:

`java -classpath target/dependency:target/classes activejdbc.examples.simple.Main`

Maven: 3.6.0

Java: jre1.8.0_191, jdk1.8.0_201

Operating System: Windows 10 (64-bit).
All commands were executed in folder simple-example-master.

Output of each command is [here](https://github.com/javalite/simple-example/issues/7)

Comment: And what do you have in target/classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that command is good for Linux. On Windows, you need to use backslashes and smi-colon in place of a colon:

```
java -classpath target\dependency;target\classes activejdbc.examples.simple.Main
```

I will update the docs